# Populate a ListBox with a dynamic list in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to populate a ListBox with the a list of dynamic length from another sheet. I want to eventually select multiple items to trigger VLookups and further calculations.

I do not get any error messages but it does not populate the box.

```vb
Sub FilterUniqueData()
Dim Lrow As Long, test As New Collection
Dim Value As Variant, temp() As Variant
ReDim temp(0)
Dim Value1 As Variant

On Error Resume Next
With Workbooks("Copy of SWR1304 (Future Development Risk Assessment) Strathaven.xls").Sheets("Non Household Metered Users")
    Lrow = .Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    temp = .Range("h12:h" & Lrow).Value
End With

For Each Value In temp
    If Len(Value) > 0 Then test.Add Value, CStr(Value)
Next Value

ReDim temp(0)
Workbooks("DMA_metered_tool").Worksheets("DMA list").Shapes("List Box 2").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

For Each Value In test
     Worksheets("DMA list").Shapes("List Box 2").ControlFormat.AddItem Value
Next Value
   
Set test = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

Without `On Error Resume Next`, `Lrow = .Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` returns

> 1004 application/object defined error

Comment: As a suggestion, try removing the `On Error Resume Next` line while debugging your code. Let the code throw an error because that will help you narrow down what the problem is, and allow you to fix it. (If you prefer, you can add the line back in once your code is finalized).

Comment: I have always written the values I want to add to the List Box to an array and then I loop through the array and add the items to the list box. It seems that this should work for a collection too, but maybe not.

Comment: @user3561813 Cheers, rookie error on my part! `Lrow = .Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` returns 1004 application/object defined error.

Comment: @squarah Are the workbook name and sheet name spelled correctly? To test, select the worksheet "Non...", and in the VBE, use the Immediate Window (if not visible, press CTRL+G). Type `? Activeworkbook.Name` followed by enter. Next type `? Activesheet.Name` Do these match your values?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Substitute lstCategory with the name of your list box control name and the Support in shSupport with the intended sheet name that has the list details. Also adjust the range from A to whatever column in the sheet that contains the list. This helps in that it's a dynamic list.
Hope this helps.

```
    .lstCategory.Clear
      
    shSupport.Range("A2", shSupport.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Dynamic"
    
    .lstCategory.RowSource = "Dynamic"
    
    .lstCategory.Value = ""
```